# can't click button with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button

i can't find way to press button with selenium. tried to click on it by name and xpath, but it didnt worked.
this is sign in button on this site - https://account.envato.com/sign_in?to=audiojungle

this is code of button:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign in to your account" class="js-sign-in__submit e-btn--3d -color-primary -size-m -width-full h-mb2 h-mt1">
```

if i try to find it by x path, using - `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign-in-form"]/div[6]/input').click()`
or using - `driver.find_element_by_name('commit').click()`

it comes with this problem -

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In"formnovalidate="formnovalidate" data-disable-with="Sign In"> is not clickable at point (789, 309). Other element would receive the click: <p style="">...</p>
```

i don't remember evrything i tried, but i hope you understood me. i didn't find solution in internet, so i hope you will help me, thx)

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code?  That will help us figure out what's happening and how best to go about helping.

Comment: Hey Alex, looks like you have async loading something, I assume you doing something else in that form prior submitting it which causing a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Option 1:

```
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"Your xpath")
```

Option 2:
Check if it is not in iframe.

Option 3:
Use Action or Javascript to click on button.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thx for your anwser, i tried to use wait.until function, but it came with another problem, i found this solution - button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign-in-form"]/div[6]/input')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

Comment: can't understend why only this method work, people who find it also have no idea why this work)